# How to transfer photos from Mac to iPhone via Airdrop?

Tags: iphone, photos, photos.app, airdrop

This may sound like an easy question, but it's pretty complicated as I found. 
I just want to simple, open my Photos application on my Mac, choose a couple / multiple of pictures to send via Airdrop to my phone and send them.

When I try to use the Airdrop option after selecting my photos, it automatically selects all and says "Exporting 21 of 2233 photos for sharing".

How can I do this easily and simply? Move multiple photos via Airdrop.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround:

- Select your photos
- Right click --> edit with --> preview
- In preview, hit the share button --> airdrop

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to finder on your mac, then airdrop on the side. Does your phone show up? If so, drag your desired photos into your phone. If not, swipe up to open control centre on your phone and press airdrop and make sure "everyone" is selected. Your device should then show up after a moment. Simply then drag the photos into your phone on the airdrop section in finder.

Hope this helps and makes sense :)

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Yes my iphone is discoverable. When I try to drag from the photos app, it selects all and say gives the message "Exporting 21 of 2233 photos for sharing". after exporting all, i don't know what to do. Also my iphone has "Everyone" on it.

Comment: Use the share button in photos. It's a square with an arrow pointing outwards. Don't use the finder.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. I wasn't using the finder.

Comment: What it you _want_ to use the Finder? (: I hardly ever use the Photos app myself.

Answer (score 0):

AirDrop works well between iOS and OS X system. Thus you are able to transfer photos from iPhone to Mac via AirDrop. With huge functions, AirDrop enables users to sync contacts, videos, music, password and any other things among Apple devices. As a result, AirDrop is very popular out of other photo transfer apps.

1.Launch “Finder” on your Mac. Choose AirDrop on the left pane.

2.Select “Contacts Only” or “Everyone” to be discovered according to your needs.

3.Go to your iPhone. Launch “Control Center” after swiping up your iPhone.

4.Turn on Bluetooth and Wi-Fi. And then choose AirDrop to select “Contacts only” or “Everyone” on your iPhone.

5.Go back to your Mac. Drag and drop images to the Finder. Select the name of your iPhone’s.

6.You will see the prompt of receiving on your iPhone. Click “Save” to get transferred photos from Mac to iPhone.

You can also choose to transfer photos from Mac to iPhone with AirDrop by using context menu or share sheet. Though the most direct way is to drag and drop photos to the devices you want to sync. Moreover, make sure your iPhone and Mac connect the same wireless network.